# How to remove inderect left recursion

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, javacc

I need help removing the indirect left recursion from this grammar:

```
A -> B (sB)*
     | dAd
     | z

B -> <id> 
     | sB 
     | A
```

So you could move from A->B->A.... without consuming any characters.

I tried to fix it a couple different ways but keep running into issues because of this bit **(sB)***

I am not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if the grammar is wrong in general.

Comment: Remove the Kleene star notation (`(sB)*`) by introducing a new non-terminal. For the rest, try turning indirect left recursion into direct left recursion through substitution.

Comment: What may be confusing you here is that this grammar is ambiguous (indeed due to `A -> B(sB)*`, `B -> sB`, and `B -> A`), making it impossible to construct an LL parsing table. It might be possible to construct an LL(1) grammar for the *language* that this grammar describes, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Before we begin, let's number your productions, so that we have something to refer to:

```
1:  A -> B (s B)*
2:  A -> d A d
3:  A -> z
4:  B -> <id>
5:  B -> s B
6:  B -> A
```

Since you're trying to eliminate left recursion, I can only assume you're trying to apply LL parsing. However, **this grammar is ambiguous, so it can't be an LL(1) grammar**. For instance, the phrase `zszsz` can be (leftmost) derived from `A` in more than one way:

```
A  ->+  B s B      (1)
   ->+  A s B      (6)
   ->+  z s B      (3)
   ->+  z s B s B  (1)
   ->+  z s z s z  (6, 3, 6, 3)

A  ->+  B s B      (1)
   ->+  A s B      (6)
   ->+  B s B s B  (1)
   ->+  A s B s B  (6)
   ->+  z s B s B  (3)
   ->+  z s z s z  (6, 3, 6, 3)
```

---

The first step would be to simplify this grammar, so that every production only has sequences of terminals and non-terminals on the "expanded" side. Rule #1 has a Kleene star, so let's get rid of it by replacing it by a non-terminal `C`:

```
1:  A -> B C
2:  A -> d A d
3:  A -> z
4:  B -> <id> 
5:  B -> s B 
6:  B -> A
7:  C -> <empty>
8:  C -> s B C
```

Now, all productions are simple.

---

Next, we identify indirect left recursion (if any), and turn it into direct left recursion. By looking at all productions that start with a non-terminal, we find that `A` and `B` are involved in indirect left recursion (through rules #1 and #6). We can break this loop by substituting `B` in rule #1 with what it can produce; we *replace* rule #1 with

```
9:  A -> <id> C
10: A -> s B C
11: A -> A C
```

Alternatively, we could break the loop by substituting the productions #1, #2, and #3 in #6. However we do it, the resulting grammar is free of indirect left recursion.

---

Then we eliminate direct left recursion (if any) in our grammar. This occurs in the non-terminal `A`, as a result of our substitution:

```
2:  A -> d A d
3:  A -> z
...
9:  A -> <id> C
10: A -> s B C
11: A -> A C
```

We introduce another non-terminal `D`, and replace these rules with

```
12: A -> d A d D
13: A -> z D
14: A -> <id> C D
15: A -> s B C D
17: D -> <empty>
18: D -> A D
```

---

The resulting grammar is free of left recursion:

```
4:  B -> <id> 
5:  B -> s B 
6:  B -> A
7:  C -> <empty>
8:  C -> s B C
12: A -> d A d D
13: A -> z D
14: A -> <id> C D
15: A -> s B C D
17: D -> <empty>
18: D -> A D
```

As stated in the beginning, you can't construct an LL(1) parsing table from this grammar, because the leftmost derivation of `zszsz` from `A` is still ambiguous.

Comment: There are parsing techniques besides LL(1) that don't work with left recursion.  LL(2) for example.  Since the question is tagged with JavaCC, it seems reasonable to assume that the questioner wants to use JavaCC. JavaCC will not work with left recursive grammars, but it will work with grammars that are not LL(k).  Similar comments hold for ANTLR.  That said, thanks for pointing out the ambiguity problems.  These had completely sailed over my head.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I can't see a mechanical way to do it. Is this how the language is specified or did you end up with it by some other simplifications? Anyway, a solution for the specific issue is to "inline" B in the left-recursive part:

> A -> (<id> | sB | dAd | z) (sB)* 
>   B -> <id> | sB  | A

Basic idea is to substitute the no-recursive terms in the recursive part and moving the recursive term to the end.

Comment: where does the <id> after the "A->" come from?

Comment: That's basically inlining the 'B' in the original production.

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
A -> B (sB)* | dAd | z

B -> <id>  | sB  | A
```

Substitute

```
A -> (<id>  | sB  | A) (sB)* | dAd | z
```

Define

```
C -> (sB)*
```

Substitute

```
A -> (<id>  | sB  | A) C | dAd | z
```

Factor

```
A -> <id> C  | sBC  | AC | dAd | z
```

Define

```
D -> <id> C  | sBC  | dAd | z
```

So

```
A -> D  | AC
```

Remove left recursion

```
A -> D (C)*
```

Substitute for C and D

```
A ->  (<id> (sB)*  | sB(sB)*  | dAd | z) (sB)**
```

Since `x** = x*`

```
A ->  (<id> (sB)* | sB(sB)* | dAd | z) (sB)*
```

Since `x*x* = x*`

```
A ->  (<id>  | sB | dAd | z) (sB)*

B -> <id>  | sB  | A
```

Same result as Sreenivasa's.

---

**Edit added after seeing @Rymoid's answer.**

At this point the left recursion has been removed, so we are done.  But as pointed out by @Rymoid, the grammar is still ambiguous and so not LL(1).  Below I will try to cope with the ambiguity, but not to find an LL(1) grammar.

One problem is that, since `A =>* sB`, the choice `sB  | A` is ambiguous and unneeded.  Let's start by removing that choice. We have

```
A ->  (<id>  | sB | dAd | z) (sB)*

B -> <id>  | A
```

Likewise `A =>* <id>`, so the choice `<id>  | A` is ambiguous and not needed. We have

```
A ->  (<id>  | sB | dAd | z) (sB)*

B -> A
```

And then we don't need `B` anymore.

```
A ->  (<id>  | sA | dAd | z) (sA)*
```

The remaining problem is that, since `s` is in the follow set of `A`, there is no way to tell, with one token of lookahead, whether to stay in the `(sA)*` loop or exit it.

The original  question did not ask for an LL(1) grammar, but since the post is tagged [JavaCC], we might assume that what is wanted is one that works with JavaCC.  That's not quite the same thing as being LL(1), although being LL(1) implies that the grammar will work well with JavaCC.

I'll assume all uses of `A` outside of the definition of `A` are definitely not followed by an `s`.  To be concrete about this, I'll assume that there is (only) one more production which is `S -> A <EOF>`and that `S` is the start nonterminal.  But really the important thing is that you never have an `A` followed by an `s` except because of the loop in `A`'s current definition.

We have

```
S -> A <EOF>
A ->  (<id>  | sA | dAd | z) (sA)*
```

When you have an ambiguous grammar but want to eliminate ambiguity, the question to ask yourself is: Which parse do I want in the ambiguous cases?  Two answers are: "Stay in the loop as long as possible." and "Jump out of the loop as soon as possible."  (Other answers are possible, but unlikely.)

"Stay in the loop as long as possible"

This is the JavaCC default, so there is no need to change the grammar. It might generate a warning. It might be possible to suppress that warning with `LOOKAHEAD( <s> )` at the start of the loop.

"Exit the loop as soon as possible"

Make two versions of `A`.  `A0` is never followed by an `s`. `A1` is always followed by an `s`. (In fact it is followed by the first `s` possible, so the `(sA)*` part is not wanted. This choice corresponds to bailing out of the loop as soon as possible.)

```
S -> A0 <EOF>
A0 ->  (<id>  | sA0 | dA0d | z) [ s (A1s)* A0 ]
A1 ->  <id>  | sA1 | dA0d | z
```

I'm fairly sure this is unambiguous and that `A0` defines the same language as `A`. It is not LL(1) and JavaCC will give a warning that should be heeded.

To make it suitable for JavaCC we can add a syntactic lookahead of `LOOKAHEAD( A1 <s> )` to the start of the loop.